# In one dive Image with title and description to it side?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to manage one image and text associated to image beside of image it goes below of image.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="200px";>
        This is a title<br/>
        This is the description.</div>
        <br style="clear:both">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Tiny you got what I ask for?

Comment: Is the answer that has been submitted not satisfactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you're trying for something like this below:

https://jsfiddle.net/up1v5j0z/28/

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="content"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZVih.jpg?s=328&g=1" height="200px";>
            <h4>Roshan Padole </h4>
            <p>Senior Software Engineer and DigitalMarketing Experts</br>Management of the manpower with effective positive results. </p>
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both">
    </li>
</ul>

 .content img {float:left}
```

Comment: My pleasure to assist you